# Azure Websites - Persistent File Issues

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are looking at migrating some sites from Azure Cloud Services to Azure Websites (as that is how things seem to be going). Cloud services obviously we were told specifically didn't preserve the file system state as they were re-deployed on machine failure.

I am assuming websites are built on Blob storage. Is there a page from Microsoft that confirms if I upload files to the site via FTP etc. that they are persistent, backed up and preserved as part of the site? If they are persistent what are their SLAs? Is there any inbuilt function to backup local files? What happens on instance scale out to files on local file system?  Can I get access to the underlying blob storage?

If they are standard is there any issues with letting users upload files in a hosting sense? I appreciate risks of what users shouldn't upload. If files are persistent is it sill best practice to offload to blob storage?

Comment: Parts answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136706/is-the-file-system-shared-across-multiple-azure-websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, files that are part of your Web Site are persisted.  You can access them via FTP.

You can use the backup service (currently in preview) to schedule backups to blob storage.

The Azure Web Sites SLA is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39303